# How to make SQL-request for UPDATE columns with condition properly?

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam so weak in SQL, please help. I have 2 tables with same columns: `quantity` and `SKU`. Need UPDATE Table_2 `quantity` with values from Table_1 `quantity` for strings with same `SKU`.

Seems it must looks like this:

```
UPDATE Table_2
SET Table_2.quantity = Table_1.quantity
WHERE Table_2.SKU = Table_1.SKU
;
```

How make that request properly?

Comment: It works! Thank you much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a inner join  update

```
  UPDATE Table_2 
  INNER JOIN able_1 ON Table_2.SKU = Table_1.SKU 
  SET Table_2.quantity = Table_1.quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use aliases and `join` like:

```
Update t2
set t2.quantity = t1.quantity
from Table_2 as t2
inner join Table_1 as t1 on t1.SKU = t2.SKU
```